# setting the PATH variable to enable LaTeX to run from the command line

Tags: pdftex

Recently I asked a question about getting LaTeX to run on the command line, 
after upgrading to Sierra. I had loaded LaTeX via Macports. 
One failure is `latex/pdftex` cannot seem to find the file `loadhyph-mul-ethi.tex`
However I can find where that file is from `/usr/local/texlive/2016`

But even when I add that path LaTeX still cannot find it.
So my question: exactly what directories must I include in my PATH variable?

Comment: Please provide more information. For all anyone else knows, you haven't set your PATHs correctly....

Comment: Just search for other answers for Sierra, it is a known problem. Also people seem to not recommend getting latex from macports as it creates more problems than just installing mactex (which was just updated to take care of the Sierra issue)

Comment: Can you please report the output of the command line "`kpsewhich plain.tex`"?

Comment: By the way, if you are able to run `pdflatex` from the command line, not finding a *file* is not a `PATH` problem.

Comment: egreg, I tried the kpsewhich plain.tex. This is what I get /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/plain/base/plain.tex  also I am not able to run pidflatex or latex from the command line.

Comment: the file it complains it cannot find, loadhyph-mul-ethi.tex, is in fact on my machine

Comment: here is an easy fix to my little problem, by adding two alias' to one's run control file for a shell, such as bash or zsh:                             alias latex='//Library/TeX/texbin//latex'
alias pdflatex='//Library/TeX/texbin//pdflatex'